# I need to return results from a 3 table join when one table has no records

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have been working on this for days and have not found a fix or solution yet. I am trying to return all results even when one table(table3) has no matching data. The default that I need to return is table1.ord_no, table2.item_no, table1.cus_no, table2.unit_price, table2.item_desc_1. If there is not a match in table3 that will give me a match for the .prc_or_disc_1 field I just need to echo 0. But as my query sits right now it will return nothing whenever table3 is empty I am assuming because of my  AND table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no statement. But it would be great to get the results from table1 and table2. I have tried to use a left join, left outer join, and an outer join. Is there any fix?

```
 SELECT table1.ord_no, table2.item_no, table2.item_desc_1,
      table1.cus_no, table2.unit_price, table3.prc_or_disc_1, table2.line_seq_no
    FROM table2 JOIN table1
        ON table1.ord_no = table2.ord_no
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 on table2.item_no = table3.cd_tp_1_item_no
    Where table2.ord_no = $multi_orders
      AND table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no
     AND getdate() BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
    ORDER BY table2.line_seq_no
```

I also tried this ridiculous query, which almost worked, but gave me an error that said I cannot receive more than one result.

```
IF (SELECT table3.prc_or_disc_1
FROM table3 join table1 on table1.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no
JOIN table2
ON table1.ord_no = table2.ord_no WHERE table1.ord_no = $multi_orders
AND table3.cd_tp_1_item_no = table2.item_no
AND table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no = table1.cus_no
AND getdate() between start_dt and end_dt) > 0
BEGIN
(SELECT table1.ord_no
, table2.item_no
, table2.item_desc_1
,table1.cus_no
, table2.unit_price
, table3.prc_or_disc_1
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.ord_no = table2.ord_no
JOIN cicmpy ON table1.cus_no = cicmpy.debcode
LEFT JOIN table3 on table1.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no
WHERE table1.ord_no = $multi_orders
AND table3.cd_tp_1_item_no = table2.item_no
AND table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no = table1.cus_no
AND getdate() between start_dt and end_dt)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT table1.ord_no
, table2.item_no
, table2.item_desc_1
,table1.cus_no
, table2.unit_price
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.ord_no = table2.ord_no
JOIN cicmpy ON table1.cus_no = cicmpy.debcode
WHERE table1.ord_no = $multi_orders;
END
```

Comment: Without getting into it too much, maybe you could just allow for the table3 value to be null in your criteria `AND (table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no OR table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no IS NULL)`?

Comment: No that doesn't work, I also tried, table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no OR table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no IS NULL AND table2.cus_no IS NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the condition `table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no` into the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` condition instead of the `WHERE` condition.
Not only will that give you a result when there is no matching row in `table3`, but it also seems more logically to me, to do this more narrow join instead of filtering later.

So your query would then become:

```
SELECT table1.ord_no, table2.item_no, table2.item_desc_1,
        table1.cus_no, table2.unit_price, table3.prc_or_disc_1, table2.line_seq_no
    FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.ord_no = table2.ord_no
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table2.item_no = table3.cd_tp_1_item_no
            AND table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no AND getdate() BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
    WHERE table2.ord_no = $multi_orders
    ORDER BY table2.line_seq_no
```

Comment: I have also tried that. It didn't work either LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 (on table2.item_no = table3.cd_tp_1_item_no AND table2.cus_no = table3.cd_tp_1_cust_no) Correct?

Comment: @Ryan Apart from the fact that your bracket would have to come after `on`, that should work. The only other thing I could think of is, that `table3.prc_or_disc1` is `NULL`. Do you need `COALESCE(table3.prc_or_disc1, 0)` ?

Comment: Im not familiar with Coalesce yet, What does that do?

Comment: @Ryan It returns the first of it arguments, which is not `NULL`. So in this simple application, if `table3.prc_or_disc1` exists, it will return that and `0` otherwise.

Comment: I tried putting that in the select statement, no luck.

Comment: Are you using exactly the query I gave and do you get results if you leave out the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `table3`?

Comment: Your query is now working, just realized the AND getdate() BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt is from table3 as well. So I moved it into the left outer join condition and it is working perfect, Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. I overlooked that possibility.